# Adding 2 Delays In Javascript Loop

Tags: javascript

I am building a javascript function that displays a popup 10 times each time for 5 seconds.

Inside my code I have something like this:

```
for (i=0; step < 10; i++) 
{
  showPopup();
  //need to add 5 second delay here
  hidePopup();
  //need to add a 5 second delay again
}
```

I have tried settimeout funcion but am not able to syncronize the delays.

I would appreciate anyone helping me to complete this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize `await` inside your loop to wait for a Promise that resolve after 5 seconds to create delays.

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function main() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        showPopup();
        await delay(5000);
        hidePopup();
        await delay(5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout` and to *synchronise the delays* use the iteration's index, here is an example:

```js
for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(showPopup, (i * 2) * 500);
  setTimeout(hidePopup, ((i * 2) + 1) * 500);
}

function showPopup() {
  console.log("@popup show");
}

function hidePopup() {
  console.log("@popup hide");
}
```

In this example, I've set the delay to `500` milliseconds instead of `5` seconds so you won't have to wait too long to see the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could do with setInterval for repeat the loop ever 5 second and use settimeout for display time of the data

```js
var interval = '';

var count = 1; //count for check 10 times

function show() {
  if (count <= 10) {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      count++;
      el.style.display = 'block'
      clearInterval(interval)
      setTimeout(hide, 5000)
    }, 5000);
  }
}
var el = document.querySelector('p');


function hide() {
  el.style.display = 'none';
  show()
}
show()
```

```css
p {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<p>hello</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SetInterval instead of loop and then stop the setInterval using clearInterval